# Check whether another action listener is already fired - JS

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I wrote a function for a big commerce store.
On their category page, there are multiple products, I need a way to track the clicks of products and add them to the cart.

[image: productlist]
This is for the add to cart->

```
    document.querySelectorAll('a[data-button-type=\"add-cart\"]', 'data-addtocart').forEach((element, i) => {
                                                        element.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
                                                            const article = e.target.closest('article');
                                                            const articleArray = article.getAttribute('data-test').split('-');
                                                            const productName = article.querySelector('.card-title').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('aria-label');
                                                            const itemTitle = productName.split(', ');
    
                                                            const data = {
                                                                id : articleArray[1],
                                                                name : itemTitle[0],
                                                                brutto : Number(itemTitle[1].replace(/[^0-9\\.-]+/g,\"\")),
                                                            netto : Number(itemTitle[1].replace(/[^0-9\\.-]+/g,\"\")),
                                                            quantitiy : 1,
                                                                position : i + 1
                                                        };
});
```

This is for the product list ->

```
let productPosition=1;
                                                {{#each category.products}}
                                                document.querySelector(\"[data-test='card-{{id}}']\").addEventListener(\"click\", (e) => {
                                                _jts.push({
                                                    track:'product',
                                                    type:'productlistclick',
                                                    id:'{{id}}',
                                                    name:'{{name}}',
                                                    position:productPosition++
                                                });
});
{{/each}}
```

If I click the add to cart button it tracks both the product list and adds to cart. Any way to avoid the product list click if I click the add to cart button?